# Flipping SVG arrow and make it point right?

Tags: html, svg

I have a path element combined with a marker element to create an arrow in SVG. However, the current arrow that I have points left, but I need mind to point right. I have played around quite a bit with the `d` attribute of the path, but I can't figure out how to flip it.

So this is the HTML for the arrow:

```
<defs>
    <marker id="arrow-5" orient="auto" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="1" refY="4">
        <path d="M0,0 L0,8 L8,4 z" fill="#5a5a5a"></path>
    </marker>
</defs>
```

And this draws an arrow like this:

[image: Flipped arrow]

So what would be the way to flip this arrow and make it point the other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to turn this: `M0,0 L0,8 L8,4 z` into this `M8,0 L8,8 L0,4 z`

just so you know why this is working: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d

essentially this is a set of coordinates. i just swapped it around on the x axis

but honestly i'm wondering. if it is like you described then the arrow should already be turned around. maybe the vector is just rotated and you are drawing that line backwards. i don't know for sure without seeing the whole svg but it does not matter. this coordinate swap should do.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I wasn't able to fully describe my situation: The paths that I'm drawing are dynamic and just needed the arrow in the opposite direction. Your solution worked 100%!

Comment: @Aborted look at Paul LeBeau's answer. he is mentioning what i basically meant

Answer (score 4):

Markers are defined so that their positive X axis gets rotated to point along the direction the path travels.

Your original marker is designed well - it points in the correct direction.  So that means that the path in your picture must be going from right to left and you are using `marker-start="url(#arrow-5)"` to place the arrow at the right hand end of your path.

Flipping the marker around may be working okay for now, but you have everything back to front. That may be fine with you, but could cause headaches later.

The better solution is to flip your path around, not your marker.

```html
<svg width="400" height="300">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow-5" orient="auto" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="1" refY="4">
        <path d="M0,0 L0,8 L8,4 z" fill="#5a5a5a"></path>
    </marker>
  </defs>
  
  <path d="M 25,100 L 350,200" fill="none" stroke="#5a5a5a" stroke-width="4" marker-end="url(#arrow-5)"/>
</svg>
```